# Убрать рамку вокруг кнопки/лейбла qss

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Есть проблема с обрезкой. Хотела в qt обрезать кнопку слева, используя круг. Делала это без layout. Слева кнопка, правее нее кнопка qpushbutton, и далее кнопка с i. Сделала send to back кнопку слева, и bring to front к кнопке с i. Таким образом, та самая кнопка с рамкой находится в центре и по слоям. Добавила к этой кнопке стиль:

```
QPushButton{border-radius:80px; 
background-color: #1E2633; 
border:0px solid transparent;
outline: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
}
```

Как видно, накидала всё, что можно и всё, что было в Интернете. Но все манипуляции бесполезны, делала кнопку неактивной/активной, не помогает.

Как убрать эту рамку по бокам (см. рис.)?

P.S.На фоне обычный виджет, который имеет цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и попробуйте как-то показать на изображении то, что вы хотите проучить.